# Permutation test for A/B testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, permutation-test, ab-test

I have done an extensive survey of testing methodologies in A/B practices. It seemed that default non parametric test choice is MWW U test. However, permutation test is known to generally have a superior power to U test except for highly skewed datasets (also permutation test seems more intuitive and applicable for any statistic whereas U test only tests whether distributions are same). Hence, I wonder is there any particular reason that permutation test is not so widely popular for A/B purposes?

Comment: "However, permutation test is known to generally have a superior power to U test except for highly skewed datasets" Where did you see that claim? If you mean a permutation test based on *means*, this is not true in general. The permutation test of means will often have lower power for *symmetric* distributions (with shift alternatives), if they are heavy tailed.

Comment: @Glen_b Here is the reference

Comment: https://www.causeweb.org/usproc/sites/default/files/usclap/2016/Final%20Project.pdf

Comment: @Glen_b I think I am not sure about exact cases when one performs better than the other and therefore my question arose. Also, I though we can perform permutation test for any statistic (percentiles, complex metrics) right?

Comment: (1) _Lack of familiarity._ Permutation tests have only recently made their way into applied statistics textbooks. Many people seem unclear about when and how they should be used. (2) _Simulation often required._ Although it is sometimes possible to find the exact permutation distribution, it is often necessary in practical situations to find the _simulated_ permutation distribution as an approximation. There is some software that uses such simulation, but mostly people have to write code for the required simulation. // You seem to think permutation tests are too seldom used; IMHO you are right

Comment: @Erik you can indeed use different statistics than the mean -- but then the claim repeated in your question would be even harder to justify. The thing you link to only appears to compare them *for the Weibull distribution*.